# How to use generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm studying Java and would like to know if it's possible to transform the two constructors below in a single constructor but using something like generics or something similar.

```
public CustomPage(User userInput) {
    List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();
    user.add(userInput);
    
    this.content = (List<T>) user;
    this.totalElements = (long) 1;
    this.totalPages = 1;
    this.pageSize = 1;
    this.pageNumber = 1;
    this.timestamp = new Date().toInstant().toString();
}

public CustomPage(Person personInput) {
    List<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
    person.add(personInput);
    
    this.content = (List<T>) person;
    this.totalElements = (long) 1;
    this.totalPages = 1;
    this.pageSize = 1;
    this.pageNumber = 1;
    this.timestamp = new Date().toInstant().toString();
}
```

Comment: Also worth a read: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)? (`stackoverflow.com`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: I edited my question with  correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities for this **flexible constructor**. Some of them use generics. But you can also use simple **polymorphism**. Your code doesn't give much context to decide whether generics are the best choice.

But here's some possible solution using generics:

```
class CustomPage<T> {

    private List<T> content;
    ...
    public CustomPage(T input) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        list.add(input);
        
        this.content = list;
        ...
    }   
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
Person p = new Person();
CustomPage cp1 = new CustomPage<Person>(p);

User u = new User();
CustomPage cp2 = new CustomPage<User>(u);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe u want this

```
public CustomPage(T obj) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        list.add(obj);

        this.content = (List<T>) list;
        this.totalElements = (long) 1;
        this.totalPages = 1;
        this.pageSize = 1;
        this.pageNumber = 1;
        this.timestamp = new Date().toInstant().toString();
    }
```